# how to disable error message in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm taking a java class and using eclipse to do assignments. They may different files I need and i would like to seperate it into different folders in the src folder of the workspace. But when I do this Eclipse gives me an error:

> The declared package "" does not  match the expected package

I am positive that these java files do not need a package assigned to them. So how do I disable this warning?

**Solved**: I right clicked the package in the Package Explorer Window and went down to

> Build Path > use as Source Folder

Error is gone now.

Comment: You should create another folder outside of the `src` folder for any non-source files.

Answer (score 2):

The `src` folder is intended for Java source code only. For non-source files, you should create another folder outside of the `src` folder. For example, you might have a project directory that looks like this:

```
project
  +--src
  +--res
  +--bin
  +--img
```

**Edit:**

After the clarification in your comments, I see that you have two options:

1. Add the line 'package assignment1;' to your Java code.
2. Do not put your source code file in a subdirectory. Move it directly to the `src` folder.

I understand that you want to keep your code organized for each assignment. I suggest that you create a new Eclipse project for each assignment. This will create a new subfolder in the folder where your workspace lives.

Comment: The src folder does have source files, except they are not directly inside the src folder. they are in a subfolder.
something like this: \src\assignment 1\something.java

Comment: @GordonLi The subfolders in the `src` folder must correspond to Java package names in your source files. In this case, you need a `package assignment1;` line at the beginning of `something.java`.

Comment: @GordonLi You might be interested in learning more about packages here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: While the compiler won't enforce this organization the same way that it does with class names in files without the same name, this is such a good thing to enforce that Eclipse doesn't even give you the option of turning this off.  Eclipse will write the package assignment for you if you want to save yourself the effort.

Comment: @Code-Guru I suggest adding the information from your comments into the answer.

Comment: But I do not want that line. I have to hand it to my professor, and i would rather not have irrelevant lines in the program. I just don't want to see this error. The source files are not linked in any way.

Comment: @GordonLi I have edited my answer to include your options. Since you don't want to do option 1, you need to do option 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Code-Guru is right. You can refer to the Eclipse help documentation for more detailed information. Here is a link that can help your understanding for the above question.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-wizard-java-project.htm